# Can one define a functional on a Hilbert space based on its action on a Hilbert basis?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I know that the actions of a functional on a vector space can be uniquely described by the value the functional takes on each element of a (Hamel) basis.   My question is,  in a Hilbert space,  would this work as well for a Hilbert basis?

For example,  if the functional is on $l^2$,   can we define a functional T by how it acts on $x_i=(x_n)$ where $x_n=1$ for $i=n$ and $0$ otherwise?

Comment: You need a *continuity* condition as well. Simply assigning any random values you want to the Hilbert space basis is not going to extend to a continuous linear map. Do you believe that two (continuous) linear functionals that are equal on a Hilbert space basis are equal everywhere?

Comment: Given continuity...it should,  considering that any element can be written as a converging sum of an sequence of basis elements, and continuity preserves that....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ \mathcal{H} $ be a Hilbert space and $ (\mathbf{e}_{i})_{i \in I} $ a Hilbert basis of $ \mathcal{H} $. If $ f $ is a linear mapping from $ \mathcal{H} $ to $ \mathbb{C} $, then $ f $ is continuous if and only if
$$
(\spadesuit) \qquad (f(\mathbf{e}_{i}))_{i \in I} \in {\ell^{2}}(I).
$$
Hence, although a linear functional on $ \mathcal{H} $ is uniquely determined by how it acts on members of a Hilbert basis of $ \mathcal{H} $, not every assignment of scalars to members of the basis will result in a linear functional. The square-summability condition $ (\spadesuit) $ must also be satisfied.

**Note:** By a Hilbert basis, I mean an orthonormal one.

Comment: This isn't strictly true - that is, a linear functional on $\mathcal H$ is *not* uniquely determined on an orthonormal basis.

Comment: @Jason, Can you give an example where that isn't true?  It seems like it would be.  We know that there is a bijection between linear functionals on $ \mathcal{H} $ and elements of $ \mathcal{H} $ (Reisz's theorem).  We also know that elements of $ \mathcal{H} $ can be uniquely decomposed into sums of the basis vectors of the orthonormal basis (orthogonality).  What am I missing here?

Comment: @Jason: My definition of a linear functional entails that it is continuous. I would call a linear mapping from $ \mathcal{H} $ to $ \mathbb{C} $ an *algebraic linear functional*. I’m also fixing an orthonormal Hilbert basis.

Comment: Given that the OP mentions Hamel bases, I would not assume continuity (since defining a linear map via a Hamel basis does not give you continuity in general).

Comment: @Jason: Good evening, Jason. Yes, of course. Defining a linear map on a Hamel basis does not guarantee its continuity, and different algebraic linear functionals may agree on a fixed orthonormal basis, as you’ve nicely demonstrated below. However, the poster does mention continuity in his comment below the OP, so I’m not sure what he really wants in the case of a Hilbert space. Some functional analysts assume continuity when talking about functionals on a topological vector space. Anyway, your answer got a +1 from me. :)

Answer (score 2):

As KCd said in a comment, a *continuous* linear functional on a Hilbert space $H$ is uniquely determined by its action on a given orthonormal basis. This follows since, if $M$ is an orthonormal basis of $H$, then for any $x\in H$ we have
$$f(x)=\sum_{m\in M}\langle x,m\rangle f(m)$$
which follows from continuity. If $\dim H=\infty$ and we do not require $f$ to be continuous then the functional is no longer determined along the orthonormal basis. Indeed, if $B$ is a Hamel basis of $H$ such that $M\subset B$, then we may freely choose $f(x)\in\mathbb K$ for $x\in B\setminus M$, so clearly there is no unique choice.